# Karate Chrome Docker image is starting but chrome is getting existed as soon as it try to start it

Tags: docker, karate, ui-automation, browser-automation

I have downloaded Karate Chrome docker image from Docker Hub. When I am starting karate chrome docker with below command, I am seeing chrome is not starting when I spin up the container.

docker run --name karate --rm -p 9222:9222 -p 5900:5900 -e KARATE_SOCAT_START=true --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN ptrthomas/karate-chrome

I am able to spin up a container on my local Macbook but when I am trying to spin up the same image on my organization Macbook, it is throwing me an error. Do you know what it could be? Is it because of VPN? I disconnected VPN and tried but same response

Expected Result: Able to spin up a container with Chrome.
Actual Result: Not able to open Chrome.

Below are some logs.
INFO reaped unknown pid 2764(exit status 0)
INFO reaped unknown pid 2783(terminated by SIGTRAP)
INFO reaped success: chrome entered RUNNING state,process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds
INFO reaped unknown pid 2824(exit status 0)
INFO exited: chrome (terminate by SIGTRAP; not expected)
INFO reaped unknown pid 2810(exit status 0)
INFO reaped unknown pid 2815(exit status 0)
INFO reaped spawned: 'chrome' with pid 2828
INFO reaped unknown pid 2801(terminated by SIGPIE)
INFO reaped unknown pid 2802(terminated by SIGTRAP)

These logs keeps flowing up and everytime it is changing the port number.

Comment: see if this thread helps. else we look forward for any contributions from the community to improve the steps or docs. note that you should be able to build a custom docker image if needed, everything is open-source: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2193 - also what you reported is most likely because your org macbook is the mac-silicon or ARM / M1/M2 which the docker container does not support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because the Docker container is not yet ready for Apple silicon / ARM / M1 / M2.

You should be able to build your own Docker image looking at the source. We welcome contributions to make this work across all kinds of hardware.

Comment: aah, I see. Now it makes sense. Yes, my new MacBook is with a Mac M1 chip. Let me try it out and see how I can try to make it work by building the custom docker image. Thank you so much for the quick response.